# how to create md5 password in php and save to database?

Tags: php

I have an existing database with users, each users password is stored as an MD5 hash.

Im trying to create a login form using PHP (Which im very new too) only I cant seem to get it to work, I know my username and password is correct yet I still receive the error that its wrong, Have I got to convert my password input to MD5 before checking the username in the table?

I currently have...

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];

    if ($password == $confirm_password) {
        $query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users (name, username, password) VALUES ('$name', '$username', MD5('".$password."'))");

        //$query="INSERT INTO ptb_users (id,user_id,first_name,last_name,email )VALUES('NULL','NULL','".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$email."',MD5('".$password."'))";
        echo 'OK.';
    } else {
        echo 'Error.';
    }
}
```

Comment: $password = md5($_POST['password']); then `$query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users (name, username, password) VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$password'))");`

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are showing code where you *insert* data into the DB but you ask about *checking* it, which I would expect that you should be using a *select* query for.

Comment: why would you want to use MD5 in the first place?

Comment: [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password-hash) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/password-verify) - both links have examples provided. Do *not* use MD5 for this.

Comment: Side note: In addition to the password issues, you've got a glaring SQL injection hole. This is also dangerous.

Comment: Btusing MD5 and not a secure password verification method you are putting your users at great risk. For theft sake emigrate to a secure method such as `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to use md5 as your encryption algorithm, but I would suggest to use better alternatives. Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), this is the official php documentation. Just using the basic example on that page would be more secure than md5

```
$password = password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Back to your question, yes, if the password is saved as an md5 hash into the database you have to convert the password in input with the md5 function and then check if your hash is valid.

Still, I encourage you to use password_hash() and password_verify().

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is "don't". Storing passwords as MD5 hashes is dangerously insecure, and should not be done. Same thing with SHA1 hashes.

PHP has built-in `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions since PHP 5.5. These should be used whenever you need to store a password.